# Boolean not breaking while loop. Assigning and checking equality are OK

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, boolean

I can't believe I can't see what I'm doing wrong as this is something a beginner like me should already be used to...

I have the following code:

```
boolean doWhile = true;
while (doWhile == true){
     String s = sc.nextLine();
     if (s == "something"){
          doWhile = false;
     }
     //DoStuff
}
```

Unfortunately, when `s == "something"`, it doesn't break the loop, but instead continues to read the rest of the code.

I've searched around and a lot of people seem to make this mistake, but in their cases they messed up with the `=` and `==` things.

I'm pretty sure `=` is for assigning and `==` to check equality.
I also tried `while(doWhile)` and `while(!doWhile)` with the `boolean` to `false`, but nothing seems to work and I can't seem to wrap my head around something so simple.

EDIT: `.equals()` doesn't work either. Also, I've used `==` in this way before and it worked without a problem. Not sure why it's making a fuss right now.
EDIT3: No solution here: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
The solution was provided by **harold**.

Comment: `==` is for comparing primitives, and *reference equality* of objects.  For *value equality* use `equals()`.

Comment: FWIW, breaking the loop can be done with the similarly-named "break". Of course you'd still have to fix your comparison.

Comment: @harold I'd like to avoid using `break`.

Comment: Sure, if you want. Then you should realize that when you make `doWhile` false `//DoStuff` will still happen once. You could use `continue` to skip it.

Comment: Thank you, kindly. This worked. ^^

Comment: `while(doWhile == true)` is extremely poor practice and will make people question your comprehension and competentcy. `while(doWhile)` is the correct form. Also `doWhile` is a terrible variable name, `continueProcessing` or something provides some semantic meaning shows you know wha tyou are doing. Also there is absolutely no valid reason for *avoiding the use of the `break` keyword*.

Comment: The more correct way would be `while(!s.equals("something"))` that eliminates the hacky boolean flag variable and all the mistakes you are making because of it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Obviously I only name the variable like that for the question, it's not called like that in my code and there's a perfectly good reason to NOT use "break", for example, not being allowed to, like in my case + if the condition is done properly, you don't need a "break".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (s.equals("something")){
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the values you're testing with `System.out.println(variable);`? It can help to know what's hapening. For example: `System.out.println(s);` or `System.out.println(doWhile);` or `System.out.println(doWhile == true);`. Maybe there is something wrong the way you are testing...

Comment: I tried printing and everything seemed fine, or at least, it showed what it was supposed to for the examples I input-ed.

I got it to work yesterday, anyway. Sometimes, I still have to use ".equals()", but not always. It's weird.

Comment: It is wierd because `s == "something"` shouldn't work. The last thing is some problem with your IDE

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ. It has never given me a problem before, though.